# Ubuntu 20.04でdocker-composeを公式のGithubリポジトリから正常に導入されたそうに見えるが「command not found」エラーが発生

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

[Digital Oceanの記事](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04-ja)通りに操作を行い、「お名前.com」のKVM（Ubuntu 20.04）に**docker-compose**を導入してみました。この質問を聞いた時点、最新のdocker-composeのバージョン2.2.2でしたらから、初期のコマンドは

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.2.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

を実行しました。次は完全に説明書通り

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

を入力しました。エラー等ありませんでしたが、

```
docker-compose --version
```

を入力してみたら「コマンドが見つかりませんでした」という反応でした。手順が変わりましたでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.2.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"
# https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.2.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64
```

を実行してみるとわかりますが、 "*Not Found*" という文字列が返ってきています。
この文字列が書き込まれたファイルを実行しているため、 *1行目の `Not` というコマンドが存在しない*

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: Not: command not found
```

というエラーが出ています。

---

Docker Compose のバージョン `1` 系統と `2` 系統では仕組みが変わっていて、インストール方法や実行方法にも違いがあります。

[Compose V2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/) より:

> The new Compose V2, which supports the `compose` command as part of the Docker CLI, is now available.
>
> Compose V2 integrates compose functions into the Docker platform, continuing to support most of the previous `docker-compose` features and flags. You can test the Compose V2 by simply replacing the dash (`-`) with a space, and by running `docker compose`, instead of `docker-compose`.

ですので、インストール作業の前に、どちらをインストールするかを決定する必要があります。

そして、 `V2` 系統をインストールすることに決めたのであれば `V2` のインストール手順を踏みます:

- [Compose V2 > Installing Compose V2 > Install on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#install-on-linux)

あるいは `V1` 系統をインストールすることに決めたのであれば `V1` のインストール手順を踏みます(※こちらが質問文冒頭にリンクされているページの手順に相当します):

- [Install Docker Compose > Install Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose)

Comment: ご回答に感謝致します。正式的説明書通りの手順でいけました。